# Delete the form data if the App is background for more than 20 mins

Tags: ios, swift, background

We have a registration form kind of screen where user enters some sensitive data, we want to delete the already entered data if the app is in background for more than 20 mins.

We do not want to keep the data forever when app is background.

Any ideas what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: May i know the reason why it was down voted so that i can improve for the next time ?

Comment: It appears to be low effort because you describe the problem but not what you did to research a potential solution. For instance can you detect when your application transitions from foreground to background?

Answer (score 1):

Get and save the time when the app goes into background.
Get and save the time when the app goes into foreground again.
Calculate the difference and take the appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks , Can we do the deletion while the app is in background instead of waiting for it to come to foreground ?

Comment: @RavikanthM I do not think so, and there is no need for it. You simply want the user to not see old information, therefore clearing it before the app becomes active should work without problems